# Convincing argument that changing variables is justified

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, algebra-precalculus

I for some reason cannot convince myself that changing dummy variables is justified.

Suppose:

$$I = \int_{0}^{1} x dx$$

I cannot convince myself that it is fine to change this dummy variable to

$$I = \int_{0}^{1} y dy$$

Is it definition/property what is a proper justification?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you OK with changing indices of summation? E.G. $\sum_{n=1}^5 n=\sum_{k=1}^5k$.

Comment: @AlexR. what is a justification for that?

Comment: That's just it, it's a dummy variable. The two integrals are exactly the same, are you getting confused perhaps by thinking there's a relationship between x and y? Because you have none.

Comment: How would you otherwise designate an arbitrary symbol? Think of it as a local variable in a programming language.

Comment: @copper.hat, so that is it? Is it the definition of a variable then?

Comment: It's the same with defining a function. $f(x)=x^2$ or $f(t)=t^2$ or $f(y)=y^2$ define the same functions...

Comment: Are you actually making a substitution, say $x=y$?

Comment: Assuming I understand what you are asking, then yes.

Comment: @copper.hat, what were you thinking I was asking?

Comment: Just broke my stack...

Comment: @copper.hat, so changing the integral is letting  $x=y$ and then $dx = dy$?

Comment: Think of $x$ or $y$ as the words it/he/she in the English language.

Comment: Yes, but it is a purely symbolic substitution. More logic than mathematical.

Comment: @copper.hat, I am confused. Is it a substitution or something else....??

Comment: Well, it is just symbolic. '$x$' has no meaning other than a place holder.

Comment: @copper.hat Which **type** of substitution? The $x \to y$ or $x = y$ ???

Comment: It is exactly the same as replacing 'a' in 'cat' by 'b' to get 'cbt'. It has no real meaning.

Comment: @copper.hat I see what you mean. Ill assume $x \to y$ since that fits the example.

Comment: Proper substitution has some semantic content, replacing a symbol is purely syntactic.

Comment: @copper.hat So in math it is legal to change a symbol? Is it from definition or what allows that?

Comment: @copper.hat ,please I might be able to understand this if you can help a little more?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking and is a little difficult to give a precise answer without getting into notions of scope, binding, free, occurrences, etc. Broadly, if you replace a symbol everwhere 'relevant' by another 'distinct' symbol then the answer is yes.

Comment: I mean, I can't in general replace $\pi$ by $e$, for example, because the symbol carries some meaning by itself.

Comment: @copper.hat yes, I meant variables, not constants.

Comment: But if I am defining a function, then $x \mapsto x^2$ and $\zeta \mapsto \zeta^2$ have the same meaning.

Comment: Yes, that was the replace I was talking about. I believe that is the "substitution," you make isnt it? What is the difference between $x=y$ and $x \to y$?

Comment: Well, you need to distinguish between symbolic substitution (a formal affair) and replacing a variable by a function in the integral (which requires mathematical justification). Just replacing $x$ by $y$ is not substitution in the integral sense, since the **functions** $x \mapsto x$ and $y \mapsto y$ are identical.

Comment: The $dx$ in the integral serves to specify which variable we are integrating over. It is a syntactic convenience.

Comment: I read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables 

It shows how free-variables are interchangeable (by definition), and free variables are the one the values depend on. So it was definition wasnt it?

Comment: @copper.hat, I have to leave, I hope Ill see your comment later! Bye! Thanks!

Comment: Well, I would think of it as a convenient syntactic device.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a problem with the fact that $$\int _0 ^1 t \ dt = \int _0 ^1 x \ dx$$
I suspect you may be thinking of $y$ as the same thing you'd find in the expression $y = 3x^2 + 2$ or something of the like. In this case, $y$ is a function of $x$, so we should really say $y(x) = 3x^2 + 2$. In the case of the integrals, however, we are not assuming that $y$ is a function of $x$. It is simply a symbol that stands for a number, just like $x$.

Consider the functions $f(x) = x$ and $g(t) = t$. Do you agree that these both represent the same line? They're linear functions with a slope of $1$ that cross the origin. Now, is there any reason the area underneath one of them should be different than the area underneath the same section of the other? No. They're both the same line. Give me any number, I'll plug it into the two functions, and I will get the same output for both of them. So do you agree there's no difference between these functions? If there's no difference, then it must be true that $$\int _a ^b f(x) \ dx = \int _a ^b g(t) \ dt$$

If you want to think of things (informally) like a $u$ substitution, this is exactly like saying "Let $t = x$ so $dt = dx$. Then make the substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes calculation is the only way to convince oneself of something.  OP, you want to know why it is justified to replace the $x$ in $\int_0^1xdx$ with a $y$.  If replacing $x$ with $y$ does not change the number that the integration produces, then it is justified.

Let's calculate these and compare.  By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,

$\displaystyle\int_0^1xdx=\left.\frac{1}{2}x^2\right|_{x=0}^{x=1}=\left[\frac{1}{2}({1})^2-\frac{1}{2}({0})^2\right]=\frac{1}{2}$.

With $y$ in place of $x$, we have

$\displaystyle\int_0^1ydy=\left.\frac{1}{2}y^2\right|_{y=0}^{y=1}=\left[\frac{1}{2}({1})^2-\frac{1}{2}({0})^2\right]=\frac{1}{2}$.

The point is, when you get to the step

$\displaystyle\left.\frac{1}{2}x^2\right|_{x=0}^{x=1}\;\;$,

you are evaluating a function at $0$ and at $1$ and taking the difference.  Regardless of whether you had an $x$ or a $y$ or a $t$ or a $p$ or a $z$ as your variable, that variable is going to get replaced by $0$ and $1$ in the end.  Therefore, the letter of your variable has no effect on the output.

Live wildly and use whichever letter you like!